# Integral of the sequence of functions diverge imply supreme of the function is not integrable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(X,\mathscr{M},\mu)$ be a measure space and consider a sequence of non-negative measurable
functions $f_n$ convergent to zero in measure and such that the sequence $a_n := \int f_n$ does not
converge to zero. Prove that the function $g(x) = sup_n f_n(x)$ is not Lebesgue integrable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g$ is integrable, then, because $|f_n| \leq |g|$, the dominated convergence theorem implies that
$$\int f_n d\mu \to 0,$$
which is a contradiction.